# Question on perturbative expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory

I am trying to expand the experssion below in powers of the perturbative parameter $\epsilon$:
$$ \left[ \left( \frac{\omega}{k} - V(i \epsilon \partial_k) \right)^2 - f^2(k) \right] \Psi(k) $$
with the ansatz
$$ \Psi(k) = \exp\left[ \epsilon^{-1} (\psi_0(k) + \epsilon \psi_1(k) + \cdots) \right] \, .$$
By Taylor expanding the function $V$, the lowest order (unperturbed) term is
$$ \left[ \left( \frac{\omega}{k} - V(i \partial_k \psi_0) \right)^2 - f^2(k)\right]\Psi(k) \, ,$$
which I have no problem with.

However, I am having difficulty reproducing the leading order term $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$, which is supposed to be
$$ \epsilon \left\{ \partial_k \psi_1 + \frac{1}{2} \, \partial_k \ln\left[ V'(i \partial_k \psi_0) f(k) \right] \right\} \Psi(k) \, ,$$
where prime denotes derivative with respect to the argument of $V$.
I couldn't seem to get anywhere close to this expression. In particular, I don't see how $f(k)$ comes into play here. Hope someone here can help me out. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what expression did you get?

Comment: @user619894 Thanks for the reply. I haven't organizaed my result yet, but it's different from the one above. For example, my expression of the $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$ term doesn't contain $f(k)$. $f(k)$ only appears in the unperturbed term in my calculation.

Comment: typically $\ln$ terms indicate a prefactor. Maybe it is a normalization term.